# Why git asks to enter merge message?

Tags: git

When I'm doing git merge, it opens editor where predefined message "Branch  merged to " is printed, all I have to do is to save file and quit. Previously it didn't ask me to enter anything and didn't open files. Where it can be configured?

Comment: Just stop using merge at all, use interactive rebase with squashing, it is more efficiently.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is because the Git and Linux kernel communities thought that the default behavior (not having to enter a message for merges) was lame since people failed to provide a summary of the work being merged.  So Linus pointed out that he thought not having an editor fire up for merge messages was a design mistake.  The maintainer agreed and changed the behavior.  Linus has a Google Plus post about it [here](https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/SrePhcj6XJe), and a discussion on the Git mailing list is [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1191100/focus=181362).  Junio, Git's maintainer, talks about it [here](http://git-blame.blogspot.com/2012/02/anticipating-git-1710.html) too.

As others have pointed out, you can pass `--no-edit` on the command line.  A lesser known fact is that you can set `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no` and prevent `git merge` from popping open the editor as well.  It's meant to be used for non-interactive scripts, but could be abused as well. :-)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `--no-edit` too in the flag to prevent being asked for merge message.

Comment: does this flag affects only merges without conflicts? is it possible to set it in git config somewhere?

Comment: I saw a documentation on git merge: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html and there it says that it's generally discouraged to use auto generated messages, why? And also git on windows uses that discouraged practice. I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

A merge is a commit. So you should enter the commit description.

Comment: "Previously it didn't ask me to enter anything and didn't open files." @dhblah

Comment: @edem It's too localized to say why it was so.

Comment: @Zaffy it's just in windows version of git it didn't ask about that, but I manually build git for cygwin and it started asking.

Comment: @dhblah Maybe windows version silently commits it without your acknowledging.?

Answer (score 1):

The section "CONFIGURATION" from `man git-merge` says:

**merge.log**
In addition to branch names, populate the log message with at most the specified number of one-line descriptions from the actual commits that are being merged. *Defaults to false*, and true is a synonym for 20.

Comment: I also found in the manual that by default git uses git `merge.ff` by default, maybe this could've affected behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure it have the condition: "when merging a commit that is a descendant of the current commit". Also found in `man git-fmt-merge-msg`: "       `merge.branchdesc` In addition to branch names, populate the log message with the branch description text associated with them. Defaults to false."